# Stack around the variable '...' was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

On MSVC 15.8.5 in debug mode I get that

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'insert_into'
>   was corrupted.

Is there a bug in MSVC or have I done something bad?

Runs fine on clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 and clang version 7.0.0-svn341916-1~exp1~20180911115939.26

```
#include <set>

template <typename... T>
struct Overload : T...
{
//support struct for combining and overloading multiple lambdas
    using T::operator()...;
};
template <typename... T>
Overload(T...)->Overload<T...>;

using BuiltSet = std::set<std::string>;

template <typename... Args>
BuiltSet MakeBuildSet(const Args&... args)
{
//takes a list of arguments if an argument is a 
// BuiltSet each element is added to headers, 
// otherwise the arg itself is added to headers
    BuiltSet headers{};

//Construct a lambda with overloading on if argument is a BuiltSet or not
    const Overload insert_into{
        [](const BuiltSet& h, BuiltSet& headers) {
            headers.insert(h.begin(), h.end());
        },
        [](const auto& arg, BuiltSet& headers) { 
            headers.insert(arg); 
        }
    };
//Fold over arguments applying the lambda on each element
    (insert_into(args, headers), ...);
    return headers;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MakeBuildSet(MakeBuildSet("a", "b", "c"), "a", "b", "c");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some _comments_ into your code so that we know what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Done

Comment: Loads better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSVC bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/346200/runtime-stack-corruption-using-stdvisit.html) so it is a flaw in the compiler.