# std::copy resulting in "Stack around the variable " was corrupted" error

Tags: c++, stl, copy

I am currently trying to copy 4 bytes out of a `vector<BYTE>` into an integer value. When my function returns, I continually get an error that my stack is corrupted (Stack around the variable 'rxPacket' was corrupted). I am running in debug mode and debugging my DLL. I stripped the function down to something very basic shown below, but I still get the resulting error. I did find [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833810/) and I'm wondering if I am experiencing something similar. But, I wanted to check to see if there was something obvious I am missing.

```cpp
AtpSocket::RxPacket AtpSocket::sendAndWait(AtpSocket::Command cmd,const void* data,size_t dataLen,int timeout) {
    AtpSocket::TxPacket txPacket;
    AtpSocket::RxPacket rxPacket;

    int rxCommandStringLength = 0;
    std::vector<BYTE> readBuffer(20, 55);
    std::reverse_copy(readBuffer.begin(), readBuffer.begin() + sizeof rxCommandStringLength, &rxCommandStringLength);

    return rxPacket;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rxCommandStringLength` is an `int`, so `&rxCommandStringLength` is an `int*`.  Let's just assume for the sake of argument that `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: to really ensure that exactly 4 bytes are being copied, you should be using `int32_t` instead of `int`, since `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes on all platforms.</sup>

Iterators (which includes raw pointers) are incremented/decremented in terms of whole elements, not bytes.  The element type is whatever type is returned when the iterator is dereferenced.

Since your input iterator is a `vector::iterator` to a `BYTE` array, and your output iterator is an `int*` pointer, `reverse_copy()` will iterate through the source array in whole `BYTE`s and through the destination memory in whole `int`s, not in single bytes like you are expecting.  In other words, when `reverse_copy()` increments the input iterator it will jump forward by 1 byte, but when it increments the destination iterator it will jump forward in memory by 4 bytes.

In this example, `reverse_copy()` will read the 1st input `BYTE` and write the value to the 1st output `int`, then read the 2nd input `BYTE` and write the value to the 2nd output `int`, and so on, and so on.  By the end, the input iterator will have advanced by 4 `BYTE`s, and the destination pointer will have advanced by 4 `int`s - 16 bytes total, which goes WAY beyond the bounds of the actual `rxCommandStringLength` variable, and thus `reverse_copy()` will have written into surrounding memory, corrupting the stack (if it doesn't just crash instead).

Since you want `reverse_copy()` to iterate in 1-byte increments for BOTH input AND output, you need to type-cast the `int*` pointer to match the data type used by the input iterators, eg:

```cpp
std::reverse_copy(readBuffer.begin(), readBuffer.begin() + sizeof rxCommandStringLength, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&rxCommandStringLength));
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. It also explains why in the full version of my code, another std::copy I have works correctly. That was really throwing me for a loop. Much appreciated. Thank you for the thorough explanation